# A sequence of consecutive numbers (H^!--)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

A character has been replaced with another character. It's up to you to figure out which one it is. Explain why that character needs to be replaced with another one in order for this *special* sequence to be complete. They are arranged from the first to the last. Good luck.

---

```
       -!--:!!!--
      !!!--:-!-
        -!-:!!^-
       !!^-:!!!-
       !!!-:!-
         !-:!!^
       !!^7:!!!
       ^---:!!
```

> ⊥NIH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sequence represents,

> times on a digital clock those are made up with consecutive primes.

The trick is that

> the list in roman numerals and it is upside down!

Once rotated, we see that

> `-` should be replaced with `x`.
>
> ```
>  2:35     ii:xxxv
>  3:57    iii:Lvii
>  7:11    vii:xi
> 11:13     xi:xiii
> 13:17   xiii:xvii
> 17:19   xvii:xix
> 19:23    xix:xxiii
> 23:29  xxiii:xxix
> ```

And the title confirms,

> `xxivH` aka 24 H.

Comment: That's it, well done!